# Books a self learner should use?

Tags: resources

I've been trying to choose what book I should use as a self learner. I have three books in mind now - Sejong Korean, Master Korean and Korean Grammar In Use. Which book would be better to learn from? If you guys have more recommendations please do tell!

Comment: For reading practice, I would recommend the Yonsei Korean series.

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on what level of beginner you are--
Are you a true beginner that cannot read Hangul? I recommend *Talk to Me in Korean*. They have a great beginner's guide to Hangul, as well as lessons and workbooks to get you started.

Are you more of an "intermediate" beginner? Meaning can you read Hangul and know some simple phrases and grammar structures? Then I recommend *Korean Grammar in Use*.

For true intermediate learners I recommend *Sejong Korean* as a self-study resource because there is a bit of a curve there.

Over all I recommend to use multiple resources for a more rounded curriculum and through understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Lingodeer, its audio quality is really good. Here's the website, they have an app too. I'm not very sure if this answers your question, but I'm just gonna leave the website here coz the audio quality is really very good :)

https://www.lingodeer.com/learn-languages/kr/en/learn-korean-online/alphabet